# Return one value from EF Core query

Tags: sql, entity-framework-core, blazor

I have a function which passed in an ID and I want to get only one user instead of a list:

```
public myObject GetUser(int ID)
{
    SingleUser myUser = new SingleUser();

    var IDStr = new SqlParameter
    {
        ParameterName = "@ID",
        Value = ID,
        SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    };

    FormattableString inputString;

    inputString = $"EXEC [dbo].[sp_GetSingleUser] @ID={IDStr}";

    myUser = _context.EditSelectedUsers.FromSqlInterpolated(inputString).FirstOrDefault()!;

    return myUser;
}
```

I get this error:

> 'FromSql' or 'SqlQuery' was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it. Consider calling 'AsEnumerable' after the method to perform the composition on the client side.

Comment: Judging by the name `sp_Get SingleUser`, the stored procedure returns one user. Therefore, the `FirstOrDefault` call is not needed.

Comment: Exception suggestion is the right way. `.FromSqlInterpolated(inputString). AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()`. If your function is not table-valued function it is only one acceptable solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `_context.EditSelectedUsers.FromSqlInterpolated(inputString).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()!` or `_context.EditSelectedUsers.FromSqlInterpolated(inputString).ToList().FirstOrDefault()!` as hinted in the error.

`AsEnumerable()` or `ToList()` will execute the query as it expects by default result to be a collection. Then you can use LINQ to manipulate it in memory. In your case to select first item or default value if collection is empty.

Answer (score 1):

If the table that `_context.EditSelectedUsers` has a primary key and you've labelled that in your data object with the `[Key]` attribute then you can do something like this:

```cs
    private async ValueTask<myUserObject?> GetItemAsync(int id)
    {
        using var dbContext = _factory.CreateDbContext();
        dbContext.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;

        var record = await _context.EditSelectedUsers.FindAsync(id);
        return record;
    }
}
```

Note that this uses a `DbContextFactory`, which is the recommended approach to using DbContexts in Blazor.